# Is it possible to restart a springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I know that by sending a http post request to http://host:port/shutdown, we can shutdown a Springboot application. Is it possible to restart the whole springboot application by sending a http request in a production environment? So we don't need to login in the server to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a thing exists, I'll be glad to be proven otherwise:

Spring boot doesn't do any assumptions about the environment it runs in. So when spring boot process gets shut down, re-starting it again is "out of competence" of spring boot infrastructure which is just a bunch of java classes running inside a JVM process.

You can find [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) a list of endpoints exposed by the spring boot. There is a "shutdown" method that you've mentioned there, but there is no "restart" functionality exposed.

Now there are other techniques that probably can help:
If the application gets shut down because of some illegal state of some spring bean, maybe it makes sense to expose some endpoint that will "clean up" the state and make application operational again. If the application has to be restarted due to changes in configuration files or something, then you might want to consider using spring cloud's [Refresh Scope for Beans](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope). It's kind of hard to provide more information here, because you haven't mentioned the reason for shutting down the application, but I guess you've got the direction.

Having said that, there are probably some different ways to achieve what you want depending on the environment your application runs in:

- If you're running in AWS for example, you can take advantage of their autoscaling policies, shut down the application remotely and AWS will run another instance for you. I'm not an expert in AWS, but I saw this working in ECS for example.
- If you're running "java -jar" just on some server and want to make sure that when your process ends (by using 'shutdown') it should be started again, its possible to use some kind of wrapper that would wrap the process in service and track the service availability. There are even ready solutions for this, like [Tanuki wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) (I'm not affiliated with this product but used once its free version and it served us great)
- If you're using Docker infrastructure you can change the policy and restart the container automatically when it gets shut down, I haven't used this by myself, but according to [This excellent blog post](https://blog.codeship.com/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy/) is perfectly doable.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Bramnik for detailed info. The java service wrapper is good stuff that might help me.   On the other hand, i find a seamingly silly but feasible way to do that.  i made another springboot application. In the app, i use java runtime exec api to run a bat which aims to start my original spring boot application.  The reason i do this is that i need to change some configuration files outside the spring boot jar file via HTTP request in an production environment. But the config does not take effect in the app even though the config files have been changed. So i need to restart it.

Comment: Hi, actually from your comment it looks like a concept of @RefreshScope beans is exactly what you're looking for, they're intended to react to configuration changes... Of course, if the present solution works for you - then why not using it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Spring boot jenkins](https://github.com/rcoli/spring-boot-jenkins/blob/master/README.md) You will also find a small article explaining how to configure the project on jenkins.

Comment: thanks for input @Panupong Kongarn, this is very helpful that i will look into. But my small apps (very few codes ) run on Windows server not Unix, or Linux. When using an ide, on changing the properties file under the classpath , the spring boot project will run a reboot on IDE, so i guess there be some api to trigger a app reboot that i can use.